# Bitbucket deployment to GKE (rollout restart). Error: couldn't get current server API

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-kubernetes-engine, cicd

Requirement: Build and push repository image to artifact registry and then rollout restart the GKE deployment for this registry.

Implemented Bitbucket yaml:

```
services:
          - docker
        name: Build and Deploy to Staging
        deployment: staging
        image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
        script:
          - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
          - echo $KEY_FILE_STAGING | base64 -d > ${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/gcp-key.json
          - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/gcp-key.json
          - gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID_STAGING
          - gcloud auth configure-docker us-north1-docker.pkg.dev
          - gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://us-north1-docker.pkg.dev
          - docker build -t $GCP_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_STAGING/$IMAGE_NAME:latest .
          - docker push $GCP_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_STAGING/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
          - gcloud container clusters get-credentials $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME_STAGING --region=$GKE_REGION_STAGING --project=$GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID_STAGING
          # - kubectl rollout restart deployment/$DEPL_NAME  << gives same below error
          - export KUBECONFIG=$KUBE_CONFIG                   << used for getting auth not found error
          - pipe: atlassian/google-gke-kubectl-run:3.1.0
            variables:
              KUBE_CONFIG: $KUBECONFIG
              KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE_STAGING
              PROJECT: $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID_STAGING
              COMPUTE_ZONE: $GKE_REGION_STAGING
              CLUSTER_NAME: $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME_STAGING
              KUBECTL_COMMAND: 'rollout restart deployment'
              ROLLOUT_RESOURCE_TYPE: deployment
              KUBECTL_ARGS: ['${DEPL_NAME}']
              DEBUG: 'true'
              #KUBECTL_ARGS: ["restart","deployment/${DEPL_NAME}"]
```

Successfully build pushed to registry.
Got below info/error after completion of `pipe` command.

✔ Successfully updated the kube config.
**48 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://104.100.200.200/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 104.154.207.216:443: i/o timeout
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 104.100.200.200:443: i/o timeout**
**✖ kubectl rollout restart deployment failed.**

Appreciate for any suggestion. Thanks!!

Note:
Have also tried `- kubectl rollout restart deployment/$DEPL_NAME` instead of pipe. Still same error.

**Update**: forgot to mention that it was private GKE. got it working by adding bitbucket ips to GKE control plane adress list.

Comment: Thank you for your question. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. Questions mainly focused on kubernetes, deployments, ... may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if your Bitbucket and service account used is properly set up and communicating with the artifact registry. You can check the following line that can cause the issue since it's trying to communicate with the registry server:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker us-north1-docker.pkg.dev
```

Also, if there is a way you can manually input commands so you can check at what part of tha YAML is having an issue pertaining to the error code.

Comment: Hey, as mentioned deploying to artifact registry was working.  Issue was with connecting to k8s.
Update: Got it working by adding bitbucket ips to GKE plane address list.Thanks !